# Drupal CMS Page Latest News Only Displaying For Admin

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have a clients page who I have taken over from another company and there is something strange with the Latest News page in Drupal.  When a user posts a news article the information is shown within a front page block and also meant to show on the latest news page.  Within the latest news page the news is only showing for when you are logged in as a user and not for people who are not logged in.

When editing the page the following query is performed to grab the latest news.

```
  SELECT node.nid AS nid, node.title AS node_title, node.created AS node_created, 'node' AS field_data_field_news_image_node_entity_type, 'node' AS field_data_body_node_entity_type
FROM 
{node} node
WHERE (( (node.status = '1') AND (node.type IN  ('news')) ))
ORDER BY node_created DESC
LIMIT 4 OFFSET 0
```

As I am not to well groomed in Drupal it could be something very basic and would love anyones thoughts.
Thanks,

Comment: Have you checked content access permission for anonymous user in your permission list ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably anonymous page caching setup on the site. You can go to configuration -> development -> performance to confirm if it is on, modify the settings, and clear it if desired.